# Vary the Random number sampling time when it control over digital clock (built in Block) with different sampling time inside Embedded MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, random, simulation, matlab-guide

My code is (inside embedded MATLAB function):

```
function y=example(t)
y=rand(1,1)*t;
```

`t` is digital clock input (simulation block) with sampling time `(1/1e6)`.  The `y` also generates a random number sequence (uniform distribution) in `1/1e6` sampling time. But I need the sampling time output `y` should be in `(1/1e3)` time.

How can I do it?

Comment: Edit your title to make it less verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your input `t` is a vector of time points defined with the sampling time of `1e-6`.  As such, going from `1e-6` to `1e-3` is a factor of 1000.  All you have to do is take your `t` vector and sample every 1000<sup>th</sup> point.  This will effectively create a digital clock input that has a sampling time of `1e-3` instead of `1e-6`.  In other words, all you have to do is this:

```
function y = example(t)
y = rand(1,1)*(t(1:1000:end));
```

Comment: I made assumptions on your time vector. Oh well I tried. Good luck!